# Logon Trigger preventing any connection

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I was testing a logon trigger to restrict connections to certain IPs. It looks like the trigger was not correct. Now I can't log in to the server even as `SA`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you log in using the dedicated admin connection? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can connect to the instance using the Dedicated Administrator Connection ([DAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)).
It only accepts local connection by default.

Sqlcmd can be used:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P password -d master -A
```

> The DAC is available and supported through the sqlcmd command-prompt utility using a special administrator switch (-A)
>
> You can also connect prefixing `admin:` to the instance name in the format `sqlcmd -Sadmin:<_instance_name_>`.

SQL Server Management Studio can also be used:

> You can also initiate a DAC from a SQL Server Management Studio Query Editor by connecting to `admin:<_instance_name_>`.

However trying to establish a connection from `Object Explorer` using `Connect to Server` in SSMS will fail with this message:

> Dedicated administrator connections are not supported via SSMS as it establishes multiple connections by design.

From a disconnected Query Editor or connected with a regular user, reconnect using either of:

- Query menu / Connection / Change Connection
- Popup menu / Connection / Change Connection

---

Once connected, [DISABLE TRIGGER](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) can then be executed:

```
DISABLE TRIGGER logonTrigger ON ALL SERVER;
```